# Hide empty src in fancybox

Tags: fancybox, hide, src

I am using Fancybox gallery with cushyCMS for my client. It will be useful if I can create more main images as a series of photos for particular thumbnail, but in this case I want to hide empty src images so there are no white images when pictures are extended and client doesn`t fill it.

```
   <li>
   <div class="wrap">
   <a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="images/GaleryPicSixSM.png">
   <img id="thumbnailSix" class="cushycms thumbnail" src="index_15_1769179488.png" caption="thumbnail 6" />
   </a>
   <img id="mainPicutureSix" class="cushycms main" src="" caption="main image 6">
   </div>
   </li>
```

Is there anyway how I can hide automatically empty src in case that client will not find relevant picture ? Unfortunately there is no possibility in cushyCMS for my client to add a more pictures under one thumbnail.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. The second image doesn't have anything to do with the fancybox, as it's not linked. So it won't show in fancybox anyway. Please clarify what your question is! Does it actually have anything to do with fancybox or do you just want to know a way how to hide images with empty src. If so, can you use jQuery or javascript?

Comment: I am sorry for not clear post. The form of gallery used in cushycms is set and explained in following link "http://www.cushycms.com/examples/gallery.html"

I want basically hide image tags with empty src.

Comment: have you looked at my answer below? It should help you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, the following code would do the trick:

`$('img [src=""]').hide();`